# Looping GRASS "v.extract" in python

Tags: python, grass-gis, for-loop, grass.script

I have a multipolygon shapefile representing different cities. I am trying to loop the "v.extract" GRASS command through the different polygons via the Python interface.
This is the code I am using:

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        city_code = (row['city_ID'])
        grass.run_command('v.extract', overwrite=True, input='six_cities', output= 'out' + city_code,
                      where= 'city_ID' + "=" + city_code)
```

Where **df** is the df version of the attribute table.
However, I always get the module error. I believe this is due to the "**where**" condition, as I tried to do it without the loop and it works (code below):

```
grass.run_command('v.extract', overwrite=True, input='six_cities', output= 'out' + city_code,
                      where= " 'city_ID' = 'CH_CH6421' ")
```

It seems that in order to run, the "where" condition needs to be within quotes. However, I cannot run the loop within quotes, because in this way python recognizes the city_code keyword needed for the loop as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prepare your `where` clause first, it should work (I use f-strings below):

**Edited**
Sorry for the mistake. If you enclose the where clause in double quotes, it should work. (tested here, this time).

```
  for index, row in df.iterrows():
        city_code = (row['city_ID'])
        expr = f'"city_ID={city_code}"'
        out = f"out_{city_code}"
        grass.run_command('v.extract', overwrite=True, input='six_cities', output=out, where=expr)
```

Give this a try, and post back.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work.. I always get this error message: "Module run None v.extract --o input=six_cities output=out_CH_CH6421 where=city_ID=CH_CH6421 ended with error".
I definitely cannot understand where the problem is..

Comment: I missed the double quotes around the where clause. See edited answer.

Comment: I tried with the entire clause within double quotes but it didn't work for me, however, putting only {city code} within double quotes did the trick! Thank you Micha your suggestion helped to reach the solution :-) Here below the full working code:
´´´
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    city_code = (row['city_ID'])
    expr = f'ciry_ID= "{city_code}"'
    out =f"out_{city_code}" 
    grass.run_command('v.extract', overwrite=True, input='six_cities', output=out, where=expr)
´´´